# Trickle ICE test page doesn't work or my setup is wrong?

Tags: proxy, turn, ice, coturn

I am trying to setup a TURN server, I installed coturn and installed letsencrypt certificates with my domain name. My /etc/turnserver.conf file is like this:

```
server-name=turn.*****.com
cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/turn.*****.com/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/turn.*****.com/privkey.pem
realm=turn.*****.com
fingerprint
listening-ip=0.0.0.0
external-ip=*.*.*.*
listening-port=443
min-port=10000
max-port 10001
log-file=/var/log/turnserver.log
verbose
user=sahin:******** #not the actual password
lt-cred-mech
```

When I try this configuration on "https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/" I get error "Not reachable"

I write these:

```
STUN or TURN URI:  turn:turn.****.com:443
TURN username: sahin
TURN password: *******
```

and I get error Not reachable?
I don't see any problems here, do I miss an important detail?

Btw, I tried this configuration with the port **3478** , and **it worked** . I got the output "Done" (I am not sure if this means "it works"). But I want to reach the turn server with a TCP port, since I will use it with a proxy server (Proxy servers don't allow other than 80 and 443 unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to the STUN or TURN URI input:
`turn:turn.****.com:443?transport=tcp`
now it says "Done"